# Positive linear functional on a C*-algebra is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

The following is a theorem of Murphy's C*-algebras and operator theory: [image]

My question: I think in the proof of theorem, Murphy uses the assumption $|\tau(a)|<M$ for positive elements $a\in A_{\|.\|\leq1}$, while there is not this assumption in theorem. How does he conclude that? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: That assumption is not made. The remarks show that $|\tau(a)|< M$ imply $\tau$ is bounded. The proof then starts by assuming (for contradiction) that $\tau$ is unbounded, thus $\{|\tau(a)|\}_{a\in S}$ is not bounded either.

Comment: @BaronVT: How does he get a contradiction?

Comment: The contradiction is that the number $\tau(a)$ is bigger than all natural numbers.